# gnome_keyring_unlock_sync equivalent in libsecret, to unlock a gnome keyring?

Tags: gnome, gnome-keyring-daemon

I was using `gnome_keyring_unlock_sync` to unlock a keyring. However, libgnome-keyring-dev is going outdated, and I would like to move to libsecret.

```cpp
GnomeKeyringResult  gnome_keyring_unlock_sync (const char *keyring, const char *password);
```

However, I can not find any equivalent function in libsecret like this. I found `secret_service_unlock_sync`, but it only accepts password from interactive user input.

```cpp
// This is libsecret version. It have to read password from an interactive window. 
gint
secret_service_unlock_sync (SecretService *service,
                            GList *objects,
                            GCancellable *cancellable,
                            GList **unlocked,
                            GError **error);
```

How could I unlock a keyring with libsecret?